# Time series (xts) strptime; ONLY month and day

Tags: r, xts, strptime

I've been trying to do a time series on my dataframe, and I need to strip times from my csv. This is what I've got:

```
campbell <-read.csv("campbell.csv")

campbell$date = strptime(campbell$date, "%m/%d")
campbell.ts <- xts(campbell[,-1],order.by=campbell[,1])
```

First, what I'm trying to do is just get xts to strip the dates as "xx/xx" meaning just the month and day. I have no year for my data. When I try that second line of code and call upon the date column, it converts it to "2013-xx-xx." These months and days have no year associated with them, and I can't figure out how to get rid of the 2013. (The csv file I'm calling on has the dates in the format "9/30,10/1...etc.)

Secondly, once I try and make a time series (the third line), I am unsure what the "order.by" command is calling on. What am I indexing?

Any help??

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove year from dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966827/remove-year-from-dates-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

For `strptime`, you need to provide the full date, i.e. day, month and year. In case, any of these is not provided, current ones are assumed from the system's time and appended to the incomplete date. So, if you want to retain your date format as you have read it, first make a copy of that and store in a temporary variable and then use `strptime` over `campbell$date` to convert into `R` readable date format. Since, year is not a concern to you, you need not bother about it even though it is automatically appended by `strptime`.

```
campbell <-read.csv("campbell.csv")
date <- campbell$date
campbell$date <- strptime(campbell$date, "%m/%d")
```

Secondly, what you are doing by 'the third line' (`xts(campbell[,-1],order.by=campbell[,1])`) command is that, your are telling to order all the data of `campbell` except the first column (`campbell[,-1]`) according to the index provided by the time data in the first column of `campbell` (`campbell[,1]`). So, it would only work given the *date* is in the first column.

After ordering the data according to time-series, you can replace back the `campbell$date` column with `date` to get back the date format you wanted (although here, first you have to order `date` also like shown below)

```
date <- xts(date, order.by=campbell[,1])  # assuming campbell$date is campbell[,1]
campbell.ts <- xts(campbell[,-1], order.by=campbell[,1])
campbell.ts <- cbind(date, campbell.ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
format(as.Date(campbell$dat, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d")
```

Comment: do you get points if you edit or something? b/c you didn't change anything

Comment: No over 2k rep there's no point, the edit is just adding code formatting (4 spaces before the line of code). As is it's a low quality answer, even if it works it does not explain what it does.